# Need help finding all lines with two instances of the colon symbol Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

As the title says, I need help finding all the lines with two instances of the

colon symbol ":", I want to find those lines and delete them.

For example

Good : `First:second`

Bad : `Fir:st:second` or `:first:second`

I want to delete all the bad ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search by regular expression. Use the expression `.*[:].*[:].*` to search for lines with two colons, with 0 or more characters before, after, or inbetween.

In the search dialog, go to the tab 'Mark'. Make sure to check 'Bookmark line' and 'Regular expression'. Enter the pattern and hit 'Mark all'. You have now bookmarked all lines with two colons.

Then, go to `[Search]` -> `[Bookmark]` -> `[Remove bookmarked lines]` to delete the lines you just marked.

[image: The result for various test cases]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a Windows file (not Unix), you could do a single Replace replacing `^[^\r\n:]*:[^\r\n:]*:[^\r\n]*\r\n` with nothing.  It works with two or more semicolons on the line, if that is your desired result.